# Complex vector bundles associated to principal bundle on Riemann surface

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I'm reading the paper "Self-Duality Equations on a Riemann Surface" written by N.J.Hitchin in 1986. He is considering a principal $SO(3)$ bundle $P$ over a compact Riemann surface $X$ of genus $g\ge 2$ and he says we can always associate to $P$ a rank $2$ complex vector bundle $V$. To be able to do this we have to consider two cases:

1. The second Stiefel-Whitney class $w_2(P)$ is equal to zero
2. $w_2(P)\neq0$

In the first case the condition is equivalent to requiring that the principal $SO(3)$-bundle is spin and then there exist another principal bundle $\tilde{P}$ over $X$ whose structure group is Spin$(3)\cong SU(2)$ and to which we can associate a rank $2$ complex vector bundle $V$ with deg$(V):=\int_Xc_1(V)=0$. Here I have my first question:

### Question 1

**In this case the rank $2$ complex vector bundle $V$ associated to $\tilde{P}$ is given by $ad(\tilde{P}):=\tilde{P}\times_{SU(2)}\mathfrak{\mathfrak{su}(2)}$? Where $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is the Lie algebra of $SU(2)$.**

Moving on to the second case, Hitchin says that if $w_2(P)\neq0$ then there exist a $U(2)$-principal bundle $\bar{P}$ to which $P$ is associated via the homomorphism $U(2)/Z(U(2))\simeq SO(3)$. Associated to $\bar{P}$ is a rank $2$ complex vector bundle $V$ with odd degree.

### Question 2

**How can we associate the bundle $\bar{P}$ to $P$ following Hitchin?**

I really do not understand the construction in the latter case. Thank you if anyone could help.

Comment: I don't understand your construction in Question 1. su(2) is a 3-dimensional real vector space (Lie algebra). Don't you want a 2-dimenstional complex vector space? Why not use the standard action of SU(2) on $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: Yes, you are right for the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ Lie algebra. If I take $\tilde{P}\times_{SU(2)}\mathbb{C}^2$, as you said, then I obtain a $2$-dimensional complex vector bundle with group structure equal to $SU(2)$ and so with zero degree (because in this case the determinant bundle is trivial). Am I right?

Comment: I think that's right, and I think the answer to your second question has to do with Spin^c structures. I'm not really an expert in this stuff though.

Comment: Oh, now I understand why that construction seemed so obscure to me. I'll take a look. Thanks.